# having trouble calling class extending Appcompatactivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

Currently my webview class extends appcompatactivity and it used to extend fragment. 
in my method I called the fragment class like:

```
@Override
public void onPostSelected(int index) {
    PostData data = PostDataModel.getInstance().listData.get(index);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    PostViewFragment postViewFragment = (PostViewFragment)
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("postview_fragment");
    if(postViewFragment == null) {
        postViewFragment = PostViewFragment.newInstance(data.postLink);
    } else {
        postViewFragment.urlLink = data.postLink;
    }

    postViewFragment.title = data.postTitle;
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, postViewFragment, "postview_fragment");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

However im not sure how to call a class extending appcompatactivty here is my class:

```
public class PostViewFragment extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoEnabledWebView webView;
    private VideoEnabledWebChromeClient webChromeClient;
    public String urlLink;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    public static PostViewFragment Instance(String posturl) {
        PostViewFragment fragment = new PostViewFragment();

        /*
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(POST_URL, posturl);
        fragment.setArguments(args);*/
        fragment.urlLink = posturl;
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

In other words i dont know what to use in place of fragment manager. I need a new instance of posturl to use for my webview each time a new post is clicked.

Comment: Why you call a class that extends `Activity` a `PostViewFragment`? This is super confusing. If you extend activity then your class should be called activity and you should treat it as activity via `Intent`, not via `FragmentManager`. You can't start activity with `FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onPostSelected()` would look like this:

```
public void onPostSelected(int index) {
    PostData data = PostDataModel.getInstance().listData.get(index);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("postLink", data.postLink);
    intent.putExtra("postTitle", data.postTitle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Get rid of the `newInstance()` method.  You don't need that for an activity.

In the `PostViewActivity` `onCreate()` method:

```
    String postLink = getIntent().getStringExtra("postLink");
    String postTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("postTitle");
```

and off you go.

Comment: i had something similar however im not accustomed to using putextra thank you!